# Executing two functions (passed in props) sequentially in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two React class components.
`Component1` is the parent of `Component2` and I have two functions (functionA and B) that are passed in props from `Component1` to `Component2`.
Nested in `Component2` I have a function, `saveAndNotify()`, that is supposed to execute `functionA` and then `functionB` only when functionA has finished executing completely.

For more context, functionA changes a state in Component1 and functionB takes that state to perform other functions.

See in code of **Component2** below

```
export default class Component2 extends React.Component {
  static.propTypes = {
    functionA: PropTypes.func,
    functionB: PropTypes.func
  }


  render() {//some code
    return(//some code)
  }
  
  saveAndNotify = (my_arguments) => {
    this.props.functionA(func_a_args);
    this.props.functionB(func_b_args); // this needs to execute after functionA has 
    finished
  }

}
```

I'm new to JS and have read about using callbacks but I haven't been able to do this sequentially. Especially since I'm not getting how to access the react class Component with the keyword `this` when I'm nesting functions while using callbacks.

I'd appreciate your guidance.

Comment: I would call functionB inside function A after what is intended to function A do

Comment: Thanks @EfraimJerszurki. The problem I'm having with that is that if I nest `this.props.functionA or B` inside a created function how am I supposed to have access to the class Component through  `this` so I can call this.props.functionB

Comment: You can only execute functions sequentially using promises or async/await syntax. The callback functions you are using would not guarantee the functions running sequentially. You can return the state in the first promise and then use it in the second promise which would be `functionB` in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a callback. Passing 2 props will make things harder to maintain, the best thing is to pass one function we can call it `functionC` that will use `functionA` and `functionB`, the `functionA` will update the state and will return it to be used by `functionB`.

Component2:

```
export default class Component2 extends React.Component {
  static.propTypes = {
    functionC: PropTypes.func,
  }


  render() {//some code
    return(//some code)
  }
  
  saveAndNotify = (my_arguments) => {
    this.props.functionC(my_arguments)
  }

}
```

functionC of Component1:

```
functionC(my_arguments)) {
  const state = this.functionA()
  this.functionB(state)
}
```